# Insert function parameter in select part of sql query

Tags: oracle, plsql

Oracle PL/SQL function that takes a string as a parameter.

What is the correct syntax for including this parameter in the Select portion of a statement.

The function is :

```
create or replace function GetHorizonTime(HorizonWindowMinutes IN VARCHAR2) 
return timestamp
IS
  RETVALUE TIMESTAMP;
BEGIN
  SELECT SYSDATE + Interval '''||HorizonWindowMinutes||''' MINUTE INTO RETVALUE
    FROM DUAL;
  RETURN RETVALUE;
END;
/

SELECT GetHorizonTime('720') FROM DUAL;
```

The select statement should translate to:

```
SELECT SYSDATE + Interval '720' MINUTE INTO RETVALUE
    FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: Why are you passing in a string?  I would expect that `HorizonWindowMinutes` should be a number.  Then you'd pass that number to the `numtodsinterval` function rather than constructing an interval literal.  You could still do that if `HorizonWindowMinutes` is a string that only has numeric data using implicit conversion but that wouldn't generally make sense.

Comment: string was the latest incarnation trying to get it to work.  I originally started with integer.  Thanks, wasn't aware of the numtodsinterval function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`numToDSInterval` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions103.htm) rather than constructing an interval literal

```
create or replace function GetHorizonTime(HorizonWindowMinutes IN NUMBER) 
  return timestamp
IS
BEGIN
  return SYSDATE + numtodsinterval( HorizonWindowMinutes, 'minute' );
END;
/
```

If you're working with `timestamp` data types, I would generally add an interval to the `current_timestamp` or `localtimestamp` rather than to a `date` like `sysdate`.  If you don't need fractional seconds or time zones, on the other hand, it would seem sufficient to just return a `date` rather than a `timestamp`.

Answer (score 3):

```
  create or replace function GetHorizonTime(HorizonWindowMinutes IN NUMBER) 
   return timestamp
   IS
     RETVALUE TIMESTAMP;
BEGIN
  RETURN (SYSDATE + HorizonWindowMinutes/1440);
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing it is this one:

```
SELECT systimestamp  + HorizonWindowMinutes * Interval '1' MINUTE 
INTO RETVALUE
FROM DUAL;
```